# WSO2 BAM Hosted Service

Tags: wso2, api-manager, wso2-cloud, wso2-bam

I am interested in trying to use the WSO2 "[BAM in the cloud](http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM230/Getting+Started+with+BAM+in+the+Cloud)" solution.

Is there any documentation about how I configure my locally installed API Manager to send statistics to my cloud BAM account?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [1] for configuring API Manager to be monitored by BAM.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM140/Monitoring+Using+WSO2+BAM

Comment: Hi Maninda.  I've seen that information, but it doesn't say anything about using your BAM in the cloud solution.

Comment: You can refer to docs under http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Multi+Tenancy+Configuration to know about using BAM in cloud